# Error While Installing single hadoop 1.x in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install Hadoop 1.1.0V in ubuntu 16.04. below are the config files.

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://xxxx:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>

hdfs-site.xml

<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
 <value>/usr/local/hdfs/namenode</value>
 </property>
 <property>
 <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
 <value>/usr/local/hdfs/datanode</value>
 </property>
</configuration>

hadoop-env.sh

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/logs

I ran below command:   hdfs namenode ‐format

start-all.sh
```

I am getting the below error. while starting :

```
2020-10-02 19:24:57,090 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean
2020-10-02 19:24:57,113 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
2020-10-02 19:24:57,121 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1412)
2020-10-02 19:24:57,123 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:330)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:404)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:277)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:529)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1412)
```

Again I ran the Hadoop format command after stopping all services. but still, I am getting below error.

Comment: check any daemon process is running `JPS`, stop all the services `stop-all.sh` then format & start `bin/start-all.sh` this may help you https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: Now it's working for me I have stopped all daemons and deleted name node and data node. and format the name node and started hdfs then its worked for me